# Regex - Modifying strings except in specified enclosures - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have found similar answers to my current needs on SO, however I am still trying to grasp modifying strings based on a rule, except in certain enclosures within those strings.

Example of what Im trying to accomplish now:

```
preg_replace("/\s*,\s*/", ",", $text)
```

I found the above in many places. It will remove spaces before and after all commas in a string.

That works great. However, if I want to exclude modifying commas found within " ", I am not sure how that rule has to be modified.

Any help? Thanks!

EDIT: I want to clarify my question:
I would like all whitespace before and after the commas in the following sentence removed, except commas found in double or single quotes:

```
a, b , c "d, e f g , " , h i j ,k lm,nop
```

Expected result:

```
a,b,c "d, e f g , ",h i j,k lm,nop
```

Comment: If you're trying to read CSV files, take a look at fgetcsv() or str_getcsv()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work (it replacing whitespaces outside "/' but not those within those):

```
function yourFunction($string) {
    $arr = explode('"',str_replace(' ','@',$string));

    if (preg_match('~^("|\')~',$string)) {
    foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
        if (($key % 2) != 0) {
        $arr[$key] = preg_replace('~\s*,\s*~',',',str_replace('@',' ',$value));
    }
    }
    } else {
    foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
        if (($key % 2) == 0) {
        $arr[$key] = preg_replace('~\s*,\s*~',',',str_replace('@',' ',$value));
        }
    }
    }
    $newString = implode('"',$arr);
    $newString = str_replace('@',' ',$newString);

    return $newString;
}
```

The @ is a placeholder for whitespaces. (So no whitespaces can be lost, i don't know why i did that, i just know that i hat problems without that)

the "if (preg_match"-construct checks if your string starts with "/' oder with sth. else for the logic in the foreach.

If the string starts with "/' every 2nd entry is inside 2 "/' otherwise the others.

Hope thats what youre looking for

Comment: That actually works very well. Its the closest I have gotten. Only one downside: any instances of @ get replaced with an empty space. I suppose I could get around this some other way. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: isn't that what you wanted? the @'s which get turned into whitespaced are those between single/double quotes

Comment: Thats fine! I meant any @ characters that already existed in the string before passing your function to them :p In any case, it works well, thank you!

Comment: just add some weird characters like @~^@ and replace them again

Answer (score 2):

http://ideone.com/bRlYz

```
$text = '"a"   ,      "   , b"';

$result = preg_replace("/(?<=\")\s*,\s*(?=\")/", ",", $text);

var_dump($result);
```

But it would fail in cases when you have something like this: `"      ,      "` - the spaces with comma enclosed with quotes and without any other characters

Comment: isn't this the opposite of what you wanted? now you're editing all commata within "" but not those outside of ""?

Comment: @Mohammer: "However, if I want to **exclude** modifying commas found within " ", I am not sure how that rule has to be modified."

Comment: @zerkms  upon testing this further, it does not seem to work on different test cases. Try the rule on this string: "a"   ,      "   , b" c d "a"   ,      "   , b"  - Only the first occurrence of the comma is found

Comment: @Kovo: and what is the expected result for `"a" , " , b" c d "a" , " , b"`?

Comment: @zerkms Actually, I found the issue, if you try this string: a , " , b" c d "a" , " , b"   - the rule fails to find the commas outside of the double quotes. Note the only difference is that the first "a" is not in double quotes.

Comment: @Kovo: then you need to rephrase your question. Initially it wasn't obvious that there are literals that are not enclosed in quotes. And I doubt it is possible to do with regex (at least I'm not sure it is a good idea to do so)

Comment: I rephrased my original, question, hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: every commata in your string is within ". with only regex this is not possible i think. Only possible if the string contains 1 or 2 ".

Comment: @Kovo: it is an example of inconvenient data format. Is real-world data in **another** format?

Comment: You might have something like this: goto country, continent with "a plane, or a boat"   - Again, this is just an example, in a clearer way. Note I am not parsing a sentence, I am parsing more of a command/query